# How to respect Robots.txt using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm testing it and Nokogiri does not seem to respect Robots.txt file. Is there someway to make it respect? It seems like common question, but I could not find any answer online.

Comment: why you just can not read robots.txt and respect it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're using `nokogiri` to do what exactly? And how does that relate to `robots.txt`?

Comment: shabunc I could, but it would be better if there is a ready solution

Comment: rdvdijk: indexing web pages. And I wanted it to respect Robots.txt file. Seems I have to use Mechanize

Comment: Nokogiri is a parser for HTML and XML. It does not get pages or spider sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokogiri parses the HTML or webpage that you give it. It does not know anything about the robots.txt file for the domain where the page you happen to have requested resides.

I presume that you want to ignore in-site links that are in robots.txt?

Since you've tagged this Rails, I'll assume you use Ruby. In that case you can use the [Mechanize library](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize) which has the facility to use the robots.txt file.

There is also the original Perl version and other language ports if you prefer those.

Comment: Thanks. Nokogiri seemed just fine until now. I'll switch to Mechanize

Comment: @BasharAbdullah Nokogiri doesn't fetch HTML pages. Presumably you were using the `open-uri` (part of the Ruby Standard Library) to fetch your URLs.

Comment: @Phrogz True. Sorry for the confusion